# combining two columns in to one using multiple line triggers in mysql

Tags: mysql

The following is my table schema:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| LicenceID    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| PassingRTO   | varchar(4)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| DLNO         | int(15)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| DateOfIssue  | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| DateOfExpiry | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| COV          | varchar(6)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| DateOfBirth  | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| BloodGroup   | varchar(3)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| FullName     | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| FathersName  | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| Address      | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| PinCode      | int(6)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| IssuingAuth  | int(7)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| IDIA         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| Valid        | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What i want to do is When i insert a new row, i want my DLNO as PassingRTO+LicenceID and IDIA as PassingRTO+IssuingAuth.

I tried the same using -

```
create trigger insert_combined 
after insert on LicencesDB 
for each row 
BEGIN 
set new.IDIA = concat(new.PassingRTO, new.IssuingAuth);
set new.DLNO = concat(new.PassingRTO,new.LicenceID); 
END;
```

but gives me an error as -

> ERROR 1362 (HY000): Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after
>   trigger ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'DLNO' ERROR 1064
>   (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 1

Now I have two questions can we do this using multiple lines in triggers? and can't we combine two columns at the time of creating the table itself? like col1 = col2 + col3?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don;t forget to change the `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger insert_combined 
after insert on LicencesDB 
for each row 
BEGIN 
set new.IDIA = concat(new.PassingRTO, new.IssuingAuth);
set new.DLNO = concat(new.PassingRTO,new.LicenceID); 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I am sorry, I dont have any idea about the delimiters, could you please explain?

Comment: Sorry My bad.. Forgot to change the dataType of the columns! Works Fine now! :)

Answer (score 2):

Please check this link on mysql triggers. When you want to make an update on the current row being entered you can't use the after clause.

check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html
When you want to use

```
SET NEW.col_name = value
```

in your trigger, please note that you CANNOT use this with the AFTER the action, and must use it BEFORE the action.

Therefore, this will work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sdata_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `sometable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.guid = UUID();
END
;
```

And this will NOT work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sdata_insert AFTER INSERT ON `sometable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.guid = UUID();
END
;
```

Also you can probably do it in the code itself before even entering into the database.